# Dropped frames OpenCV camera

Tags: macos, opencv

I'm running an OpenCV application on a mac laptop from 2008( has a 2.4 ghz intel core 2 duo processor) . I was running the same application on a newer mac and it was working very smoothly but changing to the older mac, the camera is dropping frames and is not running very well. Is there any way to fix this problem within the code by making images smaller etc? My application thresholds multiple colours and tracks them then draws lines from one position to another.

```
IplImage* GetThresholdedImage1(IplImage* img, int color)
{ 

   // Convert the image into an HSV image
IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);
cvCvtColor(img, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
//yellow
// Create new image to hold thresholded image
IplImage* imgThreshed = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);
if(color==1)
cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(10, 100, 100), cvScalar(20, 255, 255), imgThreshed);

cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
return imgThreshed;
}
```

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

```
CvCapture*capture=0;
capture=cvCaptureFromCAM( 1);
if(!capture)
{
    printf("Could not initialize capturing...\n");
    return -1;
}

cvNamedWindow("video");

IplImage* imgScribble = NULL;



while(true)
{  IplImage *frame=0;

    frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);

    if( !frame ) break;

    cvErode(frame, frame, 0, 2); // ADD this line

    cvSmooth( frame, frame, CV_GAUSSIAN, 9, 9 );

    // If this is the first frame, we need to initialize it
    if(imgScribble == NULL)
    {     
         imgScribble = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),8, 3);            
    }

IplImage* imgYellowThresh1 = GetThresholdedImage1(frame,1);
 CvMoments *moments_yellow = (CvMoments*)malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));


cvMoments(imgYellowThresh1,moments_yellow, 1);
  double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments_yellow, 1, 0);
        double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments_yellow, 0, 1);
        double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments_yellow, 0, 0);  

    static int posX = 0;
    static int posY = 0;

    int lastX = posX;
    int lastY = posY;

    posX = moment10/area;
    posY = moment01/area;


if(lastX>0 && lastY>0 && posX>0 && posY>0) 

    {
        thickness=cvRandInt(&rng)%8;

        cvLine(imgScribble, cvPoint(posX, posY), cvPoint(lastX, lastY), CV_RGB(255,100,0),thickness,CV_AA);
}
```

Comment: Show us whole code or at least the most important parts - it's impossible to say what's wrong with you code basing only on this part.